# For a Google Chrome extension, Is it possible to add options to the right click tab context menu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is supported in Firefox, where if you right click on one or multiple tabs in the tab bar, extensions can add context menu items:

[image]

I'm wondering if this is possible in Chrome. I looked through [chrome.contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/) but didn't find anything.

Comment: There's no such feature in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Chrome has the `chrome.contextMenus` [API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/), it appears its not possible to add items to the right-click tab context menu specifically like Firefox.